# How do I get column datatype in Oracle with PL-SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

I created an apex application which uses jquery, package, function and procedure to check if a a value in enter in a field can be store in a table.

At the moment It tell you "character too long", "incorrect date", etc but what I want to do now is return the datatype for an example

```
table: information 
name      datatype
ID        number
info1    varchar2(100)
.
.
.
.
```

now lets say i type some values that is over 100 characters long. I will get "character too long" which is good but I want to return "varchar2(100)" along with the message.

Is, this possible with pl/sql to return the datatype?

Comment: I know that `desc` is used to get information for a table e.g. `desc table_name;`  but how do u get for a single column in a table

Answer (score 0):

Look at the columns of the user_tab_columns data dictionary view. They have all the data type and length information you need.

Answer (score 0):

with sql your query would look something like: 
    select data_type||'('||data_length||')' 
    from   user_tab_columns
    where  table_name  = 'MY_TABLE'
    and    column_name = 'MY_COLUMN'

You can put that in your function where you do the rest of your validations.